# margin bottom doesn't push element down

Tags: html, css

I have a float then I have 2 element of

, with margin bottom of 40px, I expect the gab is 80px because each element has 40px margin box each. But the result shows is just 40px, why?

```
  <p id="P_4">
  </p>
  <p id="P_5">
  </p>

#P_4,
#P_5 {
  margin: 0px 0px 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in css `margin: top right bottom left;` you need to understand css

```
margin:10px 5px 15px 20px;
```

- top margin is 10px
- right margin is 5px
- bottom margin is 15px
- left margin is 20px

  margin:10px 5px 15px;

  - top margin is 10px
  - right and left margins are 5px
  - bottom margin is 15px

  margin:10px 5px;

  - top and bottom margins are 10px
  - right and left margins are 5px

  margin:10px;

  - all four margins are 10px

```css
#P_4,
#P_5 {
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="P_4">
text
  </p>
  <p id="P_5">
  text
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and happens because both paragraphs are empty. As soon as you put text in them, the collapsing no longer occurs.

```css
.P_4,
.P_5 {
  margin: 0px 0px 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="P_4">
  </p>
  <p class="P_5">
  </p>
  <p>c
  </p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 1em;">
  <p class="P_4">a
  </p>
  <p class="P_5">b
  </p>
  <p>c
  </p>
</div>
```